# Stopping Thread in Windows Phone 7

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7

How can i stop/abort/interrupt thread in WP7 ?

**Update:**
Came up with the following solution (queue event is part of consumer/producer Q and is not actually required for exiting thread :)):

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    //GP-HACK:Stoping the thread.
    stopExecutorThread = true;
    operationQueueNonEmptyEvent.Set();
}

private volatile bool stopExecutorThread = false;

public void Run()
{
    do
    {
        operationQueueNonEmptyEvent.WaitOne();

        if (stopExecutorThread) 
            return;

        ....
    }
}
```

**Thanks to Matt!**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Generally speaking, even debugging a thread is not straight forward. Consider logging some debug info to help with debugging.

Comment: Really ? What do u mean ? I always use debugger for concurrent things (freeze/thaw, breakpoints and so on). What problems can be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to stop a specific thread. If you really need to stop something runnign in a thread you'll need to communicate with the code running in the thread and tell it to stop doing whatever it's doing. There is no built in way to do this.

Alternatively consider a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as this supports requesting cancellation.

Comment: It's worth noting that call to [CancelAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync(v=vs.95).aspx) will only cancel a BackgroundWorker from running if it hasn't started yet, i.e. it's still pending execution.