# How to terminate process in vb.net (windows phone 7)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Hi my app currently has a process thats ongoing (even when I navigate back to the main screen of my app). Is there any code I can use to terminate all the processes on that page before it navigates back to the main screen. In other words the page should reset to its original form

Comment: Which process do you have that is ongoing?

Comment: Well im using the led code from this site: http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started - However I cannot turn the led light off, it constantly stays on

Answer (score 1):

are you asking if you can stop a certain thread(not a process) ?if so please read the following post [Stopping Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181969/stopping-thread-in-windows-phone-7)